# Does AWS throttle CPU Usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, celery, kubernetes, kops

I am new to cloud and have 5 distributed instances on AWS running the same images. I have attached an image of the CPU usage CloudWatch monitor here:

[image]

2 of my instances are running at 100% but 3 of them drop to 0%. There are still tasks being processed and I would like the other 3 instances to run without idling until all the tasks are completed. What is going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are these T2 instances by any chance?

Comment: We are currently using M4.Large instances

Answer (score 1):

Are you using T2 Instances ?

T2 instances are designed to provide moderate baseline performance and the capability to burst to significantly higher performance as required by your workload

You can get more information from below link for Initial CPU credit available for t2 series of instances.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html

Comment: We are using M4.Large instances. We wanted to avoid dealing with CPU credits. We thought this would solve the issue, but it still seems to idle with M4 instances as well.

Comment: Have you checked is there any process running  which is stuck or consuming resouces?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did figure it out. It was that as I was autoscaling celery distributed task containers, more and more tasks were getting sent to the original containers while the scaled ones only started receiving tasks the moment they instantiated. So the instances containing those containers were idling after finishing all of their tasks.